# css bootstrap - fit a site as x-small in portrait orientation and as small in landscape orientation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap to make my site responsive. I know that the Bootstrap works with four sizes:

- x-small: for screens smaller than 768px.
- small: for screens smaller than 992px.
- medium: for screens smaller than 1200px.
- large: for other screens.

And so, I would like to show my site like x-small in the device portrait orientation and like small in the device landscape orientation.

I have the viewport meta tag setted as:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
```

Everything is fine in portrait orientation, the site is shown like x-small. But the thing is that in a smartphone that has a landscape orientation as big as a tablet, it would be better to show the site as small in such wide screens, but it is kept shown as x-small.

I have tried different ways to write that viewport meta tag, like setting the width fixed and changing the scale, but nothing seems to work.

Anybody knows how to do this with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go Here http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
2. Customize
3. Download
4. ???????
5. Profit

There should also be a link in your bootstrap CSS to Customize it.

If you can not do that, they you will need to manually go through all the CSS and change the `@media screen and (max-width: xxxpx) {` to match the new layout.

Comment: That is it! Just to configure before download! thank you! :)